# State Design in modern Elevator

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

I like to implement one language model for elevator operations.

To do this I worked out on how elevator works, its time, counterweight aspect, etc. Next, I found it operates mainly by a priority queue. There is also an elevator library in Python. I found some datasets in Kaggle.

I found the following discussions, like,

[https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331692/what-algorithm-is-used-by-elevators-to- find-the-shortest-path-to-travel-floor-or](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331692/what-algorithm-is-used-by-elevators-to-%20find-the-shortest-path-to-travel-floor-or)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96278/elevator-algorithm-and-implementation

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54981/implementing-simple-elvator-algoirthm

My question is how do I order the state sequences in a simple modern-day
 office/housing elevator?

I like to start simple and slowly advance into complicated situations.

I know NBC, CRF, HMM, RNN (with LSTM, and GRU) well.

I know Keras, Tensorflow, and NLTK well.

I built NER, Summarizer, QA, Sentiment Classifier.

Any good help will be welcome. If anyone may please suggest.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to have any statistical content.

Comment: Chose RNN Many to Many.  We implemented its Python code.